# search a word in a file and print only the text betwen two separator

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to code a searching fonction that gonna read a file and print name from it, without any other of the information on that line, I found out how to print the complete line only yet..

```
title = input("\n Enter a movie name: ")
        with open("Data_Film") as f:
            for line in f:
                if title in line:
                    print(line)
```

here what look like the file it must search in :

```
1;Avatar;Science Fiction;3;2;3.99
2;Little Frog;Horror;2;3;3.99
...
```

so if I search a title, I would want it to check only from the first ";" to the second ";" as that where the movie name is and print it.

Thanks, hope my question was clear enought, english is not my native language.

Comment: so if the word(s) to search is "Science Fiction" then for 1st line of file it should only print "Science Fiction" ... right?

Comment: I'm a little confused by this question.. Is the input meant to be the title or the *genre*? Because I think the program would be a lot more useful if you inputted a genre and spit out each movie title belonging to that genre...

Comment: well the research would always look only between the first 2 ;
so if the search is "Science Fiction" its should actually print nothing

Comment: @mangoHero1

Must agree to that but sadly its for a school project that have fews thing we can't change, we MUST put every movie information in only 1 file and its must be done the ways I have put my exemple =|

Comment: You might want to look at the csv module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data file always will be in that format, and the title will always be after the second ';', you can use the native split function using the semicolon as the delimiter. This splits the line at the semicolons into an array, and the title is the second element.

```
title = input("\n Enter a movie name: ")
    with open("Data_Film") as f:
        for line in f:
            if title in line:
                print(line.split(';')[1])
```

Comment: Good solution, but you should fix the indentation.

Comment: That worked exept It still have a little problem, lets say I try to search "Avatar"

when its will get to that line :
3;test;Avatar;3;2;3.99

it will actually print test, so its don't search only between the first 2 ;


edit :
nevermind, change the in line for in (line.split(';')[1]) also and worked!! thanks :)

Comment: It would print `"test"` in that case. But assuming the organization of `"Data_File"` is consistent, you shouldn't have to worry about this.

Comment: If you want it to only search the first two items in the line, change the `if` statement to `if title in line.split(';')[:2]:`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
title = input("\n Enter a movie name: ")

with open("Data_Film") as f:
    for line in f:
        name = line.split(';')[1]
        if title == name:
            print(name)
```

This fixes the indentation and searches only between the first and the second ';'.